# How to set the content of a tab in JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

Using JQuery UI, I would like to set the html content of the currently selected tab, without knowing any id/title in advance. What is the best method for doing so? Thanks!

Comment: what does ur code look like?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a css selector:

`$('.ui-tabs-panel').not('.ui-tabs-hide').html('Content.');`